# Using mysql COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, optimization, count, performance

Why is `COUNT(*)` so much quicker than `COUNT(field)`, Even when `field` is an index?

I am using MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COUNT(field)` will not count that row when `field is null`, so there is an additional check it must do.

`COUNT(*)` simply counts rows.